# Arbitrary searches and indices in RavenDB

Tags: linq, lucene, ravendb

My data consists of virtually flat JSON objects.  Most of the fields have single values, but some have an array of single values.  It never goes deeper than that.  I have about 100 top level fields, and I would like to be able to search on any combination of them.  The user will create some ad hoc combination of search parameters at runtime.  These can be a bit complex, such as

A && (B || C) && ~D

So handle parenthesis, ands, and ors, and A, B, C, and D can be equals, contains, nots, and numeric comparisons.  I don't think I can achieve dynamic searching like this with Linq.  It appears that Lucene can accept searches like this, but Lucene can only search on an index.  Since I have about 100 fields, what's the recommended way to create indices?  Should I create one index with 100 fields?  Or 100 individual indices?  Both of those sound very expensive and inefficient to me.  Is there a better way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let RavenDB handles that, it will create and maintain the appropriate indexes for you

Comment: So if I make the lucene queries, will it automatically created indexes for me?  Would these be one time indexes?  Or would they persist and update with new data?

When I tried queries via the web UI, it gave me an error unless the indexes already existed.  Is there a flag I need to set somewhere?